# A Knight and a Jester

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> I was a knight, and a jester,
>   and I created a king for my modest friend,
>   but I was never able to guide the queen..
>
> One time I told you of things that I greatly dislike
>   on the fingers of both hands.
>   On another, the tales of the monsters, so grim.
>
> Alas, though my stories ended abruptly,
>   I am remembered -

Who am I?
Please be sure to explain your reasoning.

Comment: This is a textbook example of a good riddle.  Hard, but has a completely unambiguous answer (once you know it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [Heath Ledger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger)

Explanation:

> Most clues refer to his movie roles.

I was a knight, and a jester,

> William Thatcher in ***Knight's*** Tale
>  **The Joker** in *Dark Knight*

and I created a king for my modest friend,

> Created the ***King*** Rat music video for the band **Modest** Mouse (Thanks to Chris Cudmore)

but I was never able to guide the queen..

> From Wikipedia: "He was working with Scottish screenwriter and producer Allan Scott on an adaptation of the 1983 novel *The **Queen**'s Gambit* by Walter Tevis, which would have been his first feature film as a **director**."

One time I told you of things that I greatly dislike
on the fingers of both hands.

> Patrick Verona in ***10 Things I Hate*** About You

On another, the tales of the monsters, so grim.

> Jacob Grimm in ***The Brothers Grimm***

Alas, though my stories ended abruptly,
I am remembered -

> Died in 2008 at the age of 28 at the height of his stardom.

Comment: Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Rat_(song)